# Is it ok to have wlan0 and wlan1 with 1 usb card?

Tags: wifi

I just got a new router that supports 2.5 Ghz and 5 Ghz.  I see my pi now has a wlan1 as well as wlan0.  Looks like wlan0 is on the 2.5 Ghz band and wlan1 is on the 5 Ghz band.  Both interfaces seem to work ok.

Is this normal/ok?

Comment: Add the output of `iwconfig` to your question; edit out the `ESSID` for privacy

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is OK. All raspis with wifi, except *Raspberry Pi 3 B+*, can only use the 2,5 GHz band due to limit by the onboard wifi chip. Your USB wifi dongle supports the 5 GHz band. By default the wifi driver *wpa_supplicant* selects the 5 GHz band if available and if it has at least the same strength than the 2,5 GHz band. In `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` you can configure what association to use. Your router spawns two wifi connections, one for 2,5 GHz and one for 5 GHz, each with a separate mac address. You can scan your wifi network and look what mac address is used with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
```

You can also use `wlan1`, it dosn't matter in this case. You will find lines for example:

```
BSS 34:81:c4:fc:71:ab(on wlan0)
```

Look at the `SSID` what association it belongs to. Select the mac address from your router you want to connect and add a line with `bssid=` to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, for example from my raspi:

```
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="wlan@hoeft-online.de"
    bssid=34:81:c4:fc:71:ab
    psk="verySecretPassword"
}
```